# Convert integer to 8 byte long

Tags: perl

I'm working on generating some sequence numbers and I need to encode them in a long format, i.e. standard 8 byte, as the downstream is a Java application and the generated number should be read by Java's `Long` datatype.

I searched Stack Overflow and I could find answers in other languages, but not in Perl.

Note that the below prints in 8 bytes in ASCII form:

```
$ perl -le ' BEGIN { printf("%08d\n", 256) } '
00000256
$
```

But I don't want that. I want the raw hex values of the output to be:

```
\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x01 \x00
```

Which when scanned as 8 byte `Long` should become 256 again.

For 255, it should be:

```
\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \xFF
```

How could this be done in Perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pack() is your friend.

```
my $long = pack('Q', $value);
```

This will create a 64bit, 8 byte, unsigned integer in native, CPU endianess, however if you want a particular, ie non native endian format, adding `>` after the `Q` will force big-endian and `<` will force little-endian

Note that this only works on 64 bit processors.

From your question you want big endian format so you need

```
my $long = pack('Q>', $value);
```

which will convert 256 to `"\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0\x1\x0"`

See [`perldoc pack`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) for more info on this useful function.

Comment: it gives ````00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00```` in hexdump -C, but I want ````00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00````

Comment: @stack0114106 That's an endianess issue. You have a little-endian CPU. It's likely that you actually want what pack gives you.

Comment: @stack0114106 Or, if you are sure you want your data little-endian, then use `Q>` instead of `Q` (but when the Java side stops working, I suggest that the first thing you do is reconsider this choice)

Comment: @Dada actually it is read by a package called scala.math.BigInteger

Comment: @JGNI.. pls add ````Q>```` variant and output of them in hex formats..I'll accept the answer